# How do I implement URL rewriting in my .htaccess file?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I'd like to do some URL rewriting (Why? See [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51/why-is-it-preferable-to-use-paths-with-slashes-instead-of-query-string-variables).) so that instead of users seeing addresses like

```
labouseur.com/course-compilers.html
```

they can instead see and use simply

```
labouseur.com/course-compilers
```

(Even better, maybe I should restructure that so that it's courses/compilers.)

I'm using a Linux-based shared hosting service for my website, so I do not have administrative control of the server, but I do have control over .htaccess. The references I've read online seemed less than clear to me, so I'm looking for a little clarity and advice here.

Comment: Note that this is not something you _only_ do in the server config (.htaccess). The important first step is to actually change the URLs in your application, otherwise you will end up with a lot of unnecessary redirects (or duplicate content).

Comment: See this : Apache htaccess tutorial for beginners https://helponnet.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could actually remove .html from the files on your server and set settings in htaccess so that they get served up as html files, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Do this :

```
RewriteEngine on
# Check this condition to ensure that it's not a directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Check this condition to ensure that there's a file there
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
# Replace html with your file extension, eg: php, htm, asp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: There is more complexity here, especially if you are worried about duplicate content problems.  With the rule above, your pages will still be accessible from the old URLs.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure apache has the module and that it is allowed in .htacces files, then add:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^/myoldsubfolder/(.*) /newfolder/$1
```

Your example would require

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^/(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?)$ /$1.html
```

For a single-level directory structure and

```
RewriteRule ^/(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?)+$ /$1.html
```

For a multi-level structure.

But **be careful**

If you have the structure

```
/site/.htaccess
/site/subfolder/.htaccess
/site/subfolder/cats/.htaccess
```

The rewrite rules in the child `.htaccess` files will be relative to their parent folder and you can get into some **messy** rewrite loop situations. Make sure you use `RewriteCond` to stop them happening if you can!

Comment: Do you mind going into more detail on that last point (using RewriteCond to stop the loops)?

Answer (score 3):

As addition to above answers one can use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

`([\w-]+)` Allows letters, digits with a hyphen (-).

`(.*)` will rewrite every request regardless, which may impotent other following rules causing internal server error on accessing.

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is an improvement over the accepted answer for the specific example given in the question, however, it will fail to match the more general case when there is more than one path segment, eg. `/path/to/course-compilers`. Include the `L` flag to lessen the impact on the following rules. Whilst the `(.*)` pattern is unnecessarily general, it is unlikely to cause serious problems, because of the _condition_ that checks the file exists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use an .htaccess file to accomplish this. Simply structure your files into directories, and instead of using "labouseur.com/course-compilers.html", just name the file index.html and put it into a directory called "course-compilers". Then when you point to that directory, the index is served up by default but will not be displayed in the URL. So you could just write your links as "labourseur.com/course-compilers" and all will be well.

No .htaccess required.