# parameters in a seo url

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a URL with a query string better or worse for SEO then one without one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/is-a-url-with-a-query-string-better-or-worse-for-seo-then-one-without-one)

This should be a very simple question for seo experts. Let's say we have the following URLs:

- http://www.test.com/some-sort-of-page
- http://www.test.com/some-sort-of-page?pgid1189
- http://www.test.com/some-sort-of-page/page/1189
- http://www.test.com/page/1189/some-sort-of-page

The first one is an ideal solution. What i need to do is to somehow pass a resource identifier in the url to know exactly what this url is pointing to, since it can be pointing to a lot of different things. In the second URL, "pgid" specifies that the resource is a "page". URLs 3 and 4 specify the same thing differently.

I do not care if the URL is friendly to people, because, let's face it - 99.9% of people will never ever ever bother to remember such url no matter how "friendly" it is. So the question is: which of the last 3 URLs would be the best solution for search engines? My guess is it would be the 2nd with query string, but i might be wrong.

Thanks for your thoughts

P.S. please don't offer using the first url. There's no problem using it, but the question is not about that.

Comment: I'd go with #3 but only based on minor factors. Keywords first and avoiding query strings.

Comment: Also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51/why-is-it-preferable-to-use-paths-with-slashes-instead-of-query-string-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most forums use some kind of url parsing, so they generate links like
http://www.test.com/1189_some-sort-of-page
And later, on server side they parse page id, knowing that it is the first number, delimited by '_' (in this example).

So to answer your question, i would go with fourth one (or third), because there is nothing wrong including page id into url in any form, and crawlers like static-like pages more than dynamic-like (with query strings).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know there's nothing wrong, but in 3rd and 4th example the actual "important info" (some-sort-of-page) is either in the beginning or the end of the url. Is there any difference between the too as far as SEO ranking goes?